Converting Classic ASP to Javascript to display HTML pages
We are updating our server and it will no longer support Classic ASP.  The site is simple, I just don't know how to do it.
All in same folder: index.html, a.html, b.html
a.html:
<p>this is A</p>

b.html:
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="test1.html"><img src="images/test1.png"><br>Test 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="test2.html"><img src="images/test2.png"><br>Test 2</a></td>
    <td><a href="test3.html"><img src="images/test3.png"><br>Test 3</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

URL:
index.html?file=a
    

index.html:
<p>
  Menu
  <br>
  <a href="index.html?file=a"Show A</a>
  - 
  <a href="index.html?file=b"Show B</a>
</p>

This part is what I need to figure out:
FileValue = GetFromURL(file)
Select FileValue
  a then show a.html
  b then show b.html
  else
    "you need to select an item from the menu"
end select

I have done no coding since the original development almost 12 years ago.

I think I may have done a lousy job staing the question.  Is there no way to have Javascript display the contents of an external file on the same page?  Think of a.html as a.txt and show that files contents in the space below the menu.

no JS is in need,
just set your index.html to:
<p>
  Menu
  <br>
  <a href="a.html">Show A</a>
  - 
  <a href="b.html">Show B</a>
</p>


I need to show the contents of a.html or b.html inline inside index.html.  The resulting file for index.html?file=a would basically be:
<p>
    Menu<br>
    <a href="index.html?file=a"Show A</a> - <a href="index.html?file=b"Show B</a>
</p>
<p>this is A</p>


@AngelDeLaNoche In this case, for the equivalent to the asp server (IIS), you must use a PHP server (or other). If you absolutely want JS-> use a Node.js server

Oh hold up .. if you are trying to embed pages like that .. have you considered using an iFrame ?  citation --- > https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

And on note with @MisterJojo 's comment, it comes down to if you have a Microsoft server you can use ASP but if you don't you have to use php.

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParamFile = urlParams.get('file');
console.log(myParamFile)

You can use this topic

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

The solution is in the lines of code made in javascript that i posted above the link.
